# How do I make sure I am using the latest java libraries in my projects?

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration

Is there an automated way to update & verify dependencies inside my maven jobs so I can take advantage of updated libraries? I would like to automatically update them to get security fixes etc in a way that is automated for our dev builds.

I'm using java/maven/jenkins if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "versions" plugin, e.g.,

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-dependency-updates.html

I'm not sure I'd qualify this as "automated", nor would you want it to be completely transparent, because updates break things. Instead you could script a small wrapper around this and cause it to, for example, fail a CI build.

Comment: Giving it a try, assuming appropriate tests I should be able to automate this. We're just getting started with this project so now is the time!